Ghost requests from old versions of an android app
We monitor requests from an android app to one of our backends. We have a widget that shows all incomming requests by the version of the app that are not among the versions considered "current". That is done based on a request property where the app names its current version number string. I can identify unique devices by a unique ID they also add as a separate property to the requests.
I checked some of those devices and they actually do have the current version of the app installed. Nevertheless they send those requests on a periodic base. Which suggests to me that there are apparently some scheduled tasks left on the device that are reexecuted by android. We do indeed have tasks based on the WorkManager implementation that are rescheduled if a request fails with certain conditions (backend side issues, so probably temporary failures). I could imagine this being requests that are so old that the APIs simply have changed in the meantime and are unable to process the requests.
Rebooting those devices does not stop those requests.
I fail to understand though how it can be that a task is executed and apparently uses an outdated implementation (which still contains a reference to the outdated version string cited in the request).
Does anyone have any idea how this can be?

the app is only installed in a single version
the version string is taken from a single, central ConfigurationService instance that again has this string compiled in
no hard coded version strings exist anywhere (they come from the build pipeline)
it is only very few devices sending such requests


I would start by powering those devices off for a while, at least double the period of your periodic task. If you are still receiving those messages, then they are not coming from those devices.

@CommonsWare A good point. Indeed I also had the idea that I might be hunting a phantom. However besides the version number those requests also carry a unique device ID. Sure, any client could use that, but that would mean a deliberate attempt of miss usage, this cannot be coincidence. And also not some test case with hard coded strings. Too many devices, to diverse the picture. Nevertheless you are right, I will take care to have two of those devices switched off for a few days. Thanks. I will add the information about the device IDs to the question itself. Thanks.
